# Questions about limits to find a pdf

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a question about the following example (please see image). I fully understand the theory on how to find a pdf from a cdf and everything else, but the only thing I cannot seem to comprehend is how they determine the integral limits. If the support set is given: 0

Am I supposed to treat them as x, y and z variables? I really have no clue how to draw the support set.

Thanks a lot in advance.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXoFZ.png)

Comment: The limits are based on $0\lt y_1\lt y_2 \lt y_3 \lt 1$.  To get the density function for $y_2$ integrate $y_1$ from 0 to y and $y_3$ from y to 1.